# Order By not ordering correctly by dates in my query

Tags: postgresql, date, sql-order-by

I'm trying to order this results by date in descending order with this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.id,
to_char(d.creation_date::date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS delivered_date
FROM delivery_kits_equipment_of_visit d
WHERE d.deleted IS NOT TRUE
AND d.deleted = 'FALSE'
ORDER BY to_char(d.creation_date::date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') DESC
LIMIT 10
```

However tho this is my result:

| id | delivered_date |
| --- | --- |
| 193 | "31/01/2023" |
| 196 | "31/01/2023" |
| 195 | "31/01/2023" |
| 194 | "31/01/2023" |
| 58 | "30/12/2022" |
| 44 | "30/12/2022" |
| 70 | "30/12/2022" |
| 45 | "30/12/2022" |
| 192 | "30/01/2023" |
| 197 | "30/01/2023" |

You can see some dates from `2022` in between and then then back to `2023`. Anyway I can fix that?

Comment: It it ordered correctly. The order results you get is from  ordering by a character string (result of to_char() function). What is the data type of `creation_date`? It should be `date` or a `timestamp`. If that is the case then just `order by d.creation_date`, but it the type is text, which I suspect, then you need something like `order by d.creation_date::date`.

Comment: yes it is text. I will try doing `order by d.creation_date::date`

Comment: @Belayer you are right, it worked. All I did was replace that line with `order by d.creation_date::date` and add `d.creation_date::date` as a field

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. I hope you learned a lesson here; that lesson would be **never store dates as text** always use the the proper date/timestamp data type.

Comment: yeah I got that. I really don't have a say in how tables and database structures are build. I just do what I can with what I was given (been working here for 6 months) but yeah I definetely rather work with proper data types than having to work around this kind of issues. Thanks. Feel free to add your answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ordered correctly. The order results you are getting is from ordering by a character string (result of to_char() function). What is the data type of creation_date? It should be date or a timestamp. If that is the case then just order by `d.creation_date`, but if the type is text, which I suspect, then you need something like `order by d.creation_date::date` or `to_date(d.creation_date, 'format')`.

---

Regarding your comment that you *really don't have a say in how tables and database structures are build.* I do not doubt that, but you can and should propose **a better way** especially when be able to factually back that contention up. You may not get it now, but it is likely to pay off in the long run.

Comment: `then you need something like` ... casting text to dates will fail unless the text is already in an ISO sortable format, in which case sorting on the text itself should also work.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you are correct. My original answer (at least in thought) had `or to_date(...)` as well. Guess I dropped that somewhere along the line. Updated answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well assuming the `creation_date` column already be a bona-fide date column, you should be able to just sort directly using it:

```sql
ORDER BY d.creation_date DESC
```

If `creation_date` happens to be a text column, then it gets more tricky.  Most likely, the easiest solution would be to convert the text to a date, and then sort on it.  But as a matter practice, it is best to not store dates as text in the first place.

Comment: it is a text column, I already tried that but since `to_char(d.creation_date::date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS delivered_date` is present as a field instead of just `d.creation_date` then doing `ORDER BY d.creation_date DESC` produces an error. It requires me to add `d.creation_date` as a field. So I tried `ORDER BY delivered_date DESC` using the alias but I get same result

Comment: Are the text dates in the format `dd/mm/yyyy` ?

Comment: they are in this format `"2023-03-19 20:01:06"`

Comment: In this case, sorting should still work, even if text.

Comment: @ChrisG When the format is correct, it should be very easy to alter the data type for this column. Storing a date as a piece of text could be considered a bug. Anything will be valid, like “apple pie”, but I don’t see how to translate this to a valid date